# ISR 4331 vs ISR 4331/K9?

Tags: cisco, router, terminology, cisco-isr

We have cisco router. On its box/package ISR 4331/K9 is written. I am watching a youtube video at below link, its title has word ISR 4331

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bk-4jkb6Cwo&list=PLCiTBLSYkcoT_J235Sg1u2TtbtPCGtjS2&index=1&t=11s&ab_channel=CSCORouting

Now i am confused, whether this video is about our router or about any other router?

Answer (score 2):

> K9 is both an ordering code as well as a designator in an image
> filename to indicate that the unit has the strong encryption license
> included. On a ASA, that means the 3DES-AES license.

https://community.cisco.com/t5/network-security/what-does-k9-mean-2-identical-units-for-failover/td-p/3077202

So, unless you're in a country affected by export control, you'll always have a -K9 unit. If not, the license for upgrading is free.